# How can I use Generics to clean up this code?

Tags: c#, generics

I am building a set of WCF services, and one of the things I always have to do is create the Response message at the end of each operation.
I currently have a `Mapper` class which holds a number of these creation methods, (30+ and counting), however I am sure that I can do the same with `Generics`.

A couple of examples of the methods are as follows:

```
    public ClientResponse CreateClientResponse(Header inboundHeader, ClientData data)
    {
        var response = new ClientResponse () {
            Header = inboundHeader,
            Data = data
        };

        return response;
    }

    public OrderResponse CreateOrderResponse(GenericHeader inboundHeader, List<OrderData> data)
    {
        var response = new OrderResponse() {
            Header = inboundHeader,
            Data = data
        };

        return response;
    }
```

The `ClientResponse` and `OrderResponse` are not currently connected in any way, but both look the same with regards Methods/Properties etc:

```
public class ClientResponse
{
    public ClientResponse()
    {
        Header = new GenericHeader();
        Data = new ClientData();
    }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public GenericHeader Header { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public ClientData Data {get; set;}
}
```

My first attempt was to introduce an `IResponse<T>` which had the two Properties, and add that to the response classes:

```
public interface IResponse<T>
{
    GenericHeader Header { get; set; }
    T Data { get; set; }
}
```

And then use that in my Generic method:

```
public TOut CreateResponse<TOut, TIn>(GenericHeader inboundHeader, TIn data) where TOut : new()
{
    var response = new TOut();
    response.Header = inboundHeader;
    response.Data = data;
    return response;
}
```

So I can call it as so:

```
var result = CreateResponse<ClientResponse, ClientData>(new GenericHeader(), new ClientData());
```

**But...**
Obviously the generics code wont work, because the `TOut` doesn't know about the `Header` and `Data` properties.

I think I need to use the Interface here, but I'm getting lost, and I'm not sure how I return the concrete class of `TOut` if I am changing that to work on an interface.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Don't you need to add the interface to the type constraint in the generic method, i.e. something like `where TOut : new(), IResponse<TIn>`

Comment: Hmm, sounds wrong.  Surely the response if very strongly correlated to the *specific* message and not dependent on any particular type.  So just have the message handler method return a response object.

Comment: Add to your constraint an Interface... Like "where TOut : IMyContract, new()"

Comment: Basically, you would need a generic hierarchy to do what you want, in other words have TOut being a specific type taking generics for the header and data. I think that might get messy. Just trying to think of a neater architecture to get what you want.

Comment: @stuartd: Added the code as you said, and it worked perfectly. I just needed to move the `new()` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Add a header generic argument to your response. You might then want to use a fluent builder syntax for prettyness (not included here).

```
public interface IResponse<TData,THeader>
{
    THeader Header { get; set; }
    TData Data { get; set; }
}

public TOut CreateResponse<TOut, TIn,THeader>(TIn data) 
    where TOut : IResponse<TIn,THeader>,new(), THeader: new()
    => new TOut(){ Header = new THeader(), Data = data,};

var result = CreateResponse<ClientResponse, ClientData,GenericHeader>(new ClientData());
```

Comment: Haha, I was about to test the exact same thing!